# Why does this simple XSD not validate?

Tags: xml, xsd

I'm trying to write my first xsd schema, and have run into an issue. I came up with the simplest XSD I could... but it doesn't validate. What am I doing wrong here?

linux command prompt:

```
user@computer:~$ xmllint --valid --schema test.xsd test.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE configuration SYSTEM "test.dtd">
<configuration/>
test.xml:3: element configuration: Schemas validity error : Element 'configuration': No matching global declaration available for the validation root.
test.xml fails to validate
```

test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!DOCTYPE configuration SYSTEM "rcXMLAPI.dtd">
<configuration/>
```

test.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.w3schools.com" xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com" elementFormDefault="qualified">

<xs:element name="configuration">
</xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The XML namespace is wrong on your example.  Try this instead...

```
   <?xml version="1.0" ?> 
   <!DOCTYPE configuration SYSTEM "rcXMLAPI.dtd"> 
   <configuration xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com" />
```

Comment: Ah, I saw "w3" in there and completely ignored that it wasn't "w3.org". Thanks for the help!

Comment: Personally I'd avoid anything from w3schools like the plague. http://w3fools.com/

Comment: @James, most of the points made on that site are worthless.  W3Schools is a great place for a quick intro or reminder.  You can't expect any to be 100% with everything.  Relax and take the zealotry elsewhere.

Comment: @Matthew, not zealous, just had some bad experiences with them in the past. There's better stuff out there. Been a while since I looked but I seem to remember xml.com being a half decent resource for a quick intro. I should have been more constructive in my original comment though :-)

Comment: I have to say I think w3schools do an excellent job of providing the basic information you need 90% of the time, without troubling you with edge cases. If you use it in that spirit, it's a great resource. But it should never be cited as an authority.

Answer (score 1):

Your schema is looking for a configuration element from the "http://www.w3schools.com" namespace.
Your configuration element in your XML has no namepsce.